# Redirect page when site is loaded from inside an Iframe?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a situation where I have created a website that client is not wanting other developers to be able to iframe, but instead when someone uses an iframe it would then redirect the user to the site that the iframe is trying to pull through.

I have been looking into code that would allow me to detect if the clients site is loaded in an iframe and to then redirect it back to that site. Being quite new to the JS scene I am not 100% sure on how to go about this.

So far I have the redirect code that would be put in a document.ready function

```
var url = "http://google.com";
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

So the problem now comes in is utilising that redirect by detecting that another developer is using my site in an iframe on another site.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To jump out from iframe you can do something like this:

```
// if the location of the top (topmost browser window) not equal to the current location then it redirects to the URL of the current window (iframe)
if (window.top.location != document.location) {
    window.top.location.href = document.location.href;
}
```

Comment: "top.location", what exactly is this detecting?

Comment: Oh wait i see. So the logic is that it is going to check the actual page that its on url, then if it is not equal to the specified site of my client, it will redirect?

Comment: Beautiful. Works perfectly